# Change Ajax query dataType according to return data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have ajax method which call a method

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: "/DeviceUsage/Return",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: 'HTML',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ dev: { DeviceInstanceId: $('#DeviceInstanceId').val(), UserId: "1", StorageId: $('#StorageId').val() } }),
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert("wystąpił nieokreślony błąd " + data);
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.ok) {
                            $("#Modal").modal('hide');
                            window.location = data.newurl;
                        }
                        else {
                            $('.modal-body').html(data);
                        }                  
                    }
                })
```

That method can return HTML Data or JSON data according to if method ended succesfully

```
 return PartialView(dev)   <=== Html
 return Json(new { ok = true, newurl = Url.Action("MyDevices") });;<=== JSON
```

But In `Ajax` datatype I can set only Html or JSON. If I set first the redirect wont work. If json then PartialView wont work. Is there any possibility to dynamically set dataType?

Comment: Hi - is there any way you can tell what it'll be from the frontend before the request is made? I think impossible tbh. unless you change to use something else like a xhttprequest or seomthing there maybe possibility there.. but for $.ajax i think not..

Comment: There is no way to now that before request. The method check user data input and decide if its valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try not giving dataType as jQuery tries to determinate correct format for you;

> dataType (default: **Intelligent Guess** (xml, json, script, or html))

if this does not work use html (plain text) just check some keyword in the response data and use the data according to this. For example;

```
if (data.indexOf("html") > -1) {
   $('.modal-body').html(data);
}
else {
   var objData = JSON.parse(data);
   window.location = objData.newurl;
}
```